# django - 2 views in one template

Tags: django-views

i have 2 different views which are getting filtered data from db. and i have to use these views in one template file(admin.html) but i cant use multiple views on a page at same time.

here is my view1:

```
draft_list = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=True).order_by("-posted")
            return render_to_response('userside/admin.html',
                     {'draft_list':draft_list,},
                     context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

view2 :

```
publish_list = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=False).order_by("-posted")
            return render_to_response('userside/admin.html',
                {'publish_list':publish_list,},
                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

i d like to use them like :

```
{% for d in draft_list %}
{{ d.title }}
{% endfor %}

--

{% for p in publish_list %}
{{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

i want to make these 2 views 'one view' .what is the correct way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You do not want to have 2 views in 1 template (which is not possible anyway), but have 2 models available in 1 template for rendering. Just do it like this:

```
draft_list = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=True).order_by("-posted")
publish_list = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=False).order_by("-posted")
return render_to_response('userside/admin.html',
                 {'draft_list':draft_list,'publish_list':publish_list})
```

Comment: i cant vote any answers till i have 15 rep. when i reach that. i will vote this up :)

Answer (score 7):

From your question, it seems that you're using function based views. An alternative way to solve the problem you're having is to use class based views and override the [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/) method to pass your template two contexts, one for each queryset.

```
#views.py
class MyClassBasedView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'draft_list'
    template='my-template'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=True).order_by("-posted")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(MyClassBasedView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['publish_list'] = Post.objects.filter(isdraft=False).order_by("-posted")
       return context
```