# Django partially restricting contents according to different user group

Tags: python, django

Just started Django last week and I am facing this problem regarding two types of users (normal and VIP) and how to restrict normal users from viewing VIP contents.

I am using Django with MySQL. My site does not requires user to signup but instead, I will be giving them username/password. I manually creates user via Django admin and group them according to VIP or normal. I will be uploading contents (again via admin) and I have a Boolean check-box that determine whether it is a VIP content or not.

What I done so far:

1. User must login to view the contents
2. Upon logging in, VIPs can see VIP contents and normal users will not be able to see VIP contents.

**FAQ.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
...skipping...
{% for faqs in fq reversed %}
<a href="{% url 'faq_topics' faqs.pk %}">{{ faqs.name }}</a>
{{ endfor }}
```

**faq_topics.html**

```
<h2>{{ faqs.name }}</h2>
<h6 style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px">{{ faqs.description|linebreaksbr }}</h6>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('faq/', views.faq, name='faq'),
url(r'^faq/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.faq_topics, name='faq_topics'),]
```

**views.py**

```
def is_user(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='User').exists()

def is_vip(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='VIP').exists()

@login_required
@user_passes_test(is_user)
def faq(request):
    fq = FAQ.objects.filter(vip_only=False)
    return render(request, 'faq.html', {'fq':fq})
```

**models.py**

```
class FAQ(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    vip_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Error Case**

3 FAQ entries are made, the first one is classified as VIP only.

When a normal user log in into FAQ section, he/she will only see 2 contents

*Welcome to FAQ section*

1. *127.0.0.1:8000/faq/3/*
2. *127.0.0.1:8000/faq/2/*

However, the user can easily guess that faq/1/ exists and when they actually tries, they can have access to vip contents too.

I have been searching the web for the past 2 days, I learn how to user  @user_passes_test to restrict users and objects.filter(vip_only=False) to restrict contents.

Additionally, I wish to have my views.py controlling the contents for both kind of user but I have yet to implement that yet. Will be very grateful if someone can teach me how to implement "2 views in one templates".

I have read from,

[show different content based on logged in user django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794518/show-different-content-based-on-logged-in-user-django)

[django - 2 views in one template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046689/django-2-views-in-one-template)

**My solution for splitting user**

```
    @login_required
    def faq(request):
        '''user is separate using groups'''
        if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.groups.filter(name='VIP').exists():
            fq = FAQ.objects.all()
        else:
            fq = FAQ.objects.filter(vip_only=False)
        return render(request, 'faq.html', {'fq':fq})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
def faq(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        fq = FAQ.objects.all()
    else:
        fq = FAQ.objects.filter(vip_only=False)
    return render(request, 'faq.html', {'fq':fq})
```

You can also use similar approach for doing things in the template:

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
  #...show what you only want to show the superuser
{% endif %}
```

And in your method for the single faq, do something like:

```
def faq_topics(request, pk):
    faq_item=FAQ.objects.get(id=pk)
    if not request.user.is_superuser and not request.user.groups.filter(name='VIP').exists(): 
        if fqa_item.vip_only:
            return render(request, 'path_to_access_error_template', {'fq':faq_nr})
    return render(request, 'faq_item.html', {'fq':faq_nr})
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I tried request.user.is_superuser and it works only when i sign in as admin and while I sign in as normal user, I still can access the VIP contents by directly enter the url (127.0.0.1:8000/faq/1/)

Comment: To which view function does the Faq/1 request go to? For sure not the view shown above as it has a parameter. You need to add the @loginrequired to this other view too. Can you show your urls.py?

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I have added the urls and faq_details. I found out that the superuser method alone is insufficient and I have attached my solution as well. Please comment.